# aws amplify create user after auth in flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify, flutteramplify

please i am stuck with my auth flow in flutter after my confirm registration with aws amplify . The idea is to create a user exactly after the user has completed his registration by retrieving the userid and creating a user with the id but it keeps returning null even after the registration.

In summary what i am trying to archieve is to not return null after the user as confirmed registration.
please if anyone have a solution or have series of better ideas i am really open to anything that would work.

this is my repository below.

```
@override
  Future<String?> get user async {
    try {
      final awsUser = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
      return awsUser.userId;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

@override
  Future<String?> confirmSignUp({
    required String email,
    required String confirmationCode,
  }) async {
    try {
      final res = await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
        username: email,
        confirmationCode: confirmationCode,
      );
      return res.isSignUpComplete ? user : null;
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      throw AuthFailure(message: e.message);
    }
  }
@override
  Future<void> createNewUser({
    required String username,
    required String emailAddress,
    required String userId,
  }) async {
    try {
      final newUser = User(
        id: userId,
        username: username,
        email: emailAddress,
        dateCreated: TemporalDateTime.now(),
        
      );
      await Amplify.DataStore.save(newUser);
    } on DataStoreException catch (e) {
      throw OtherFailure(message: e.message);
    }
  }
```

This is my bloc below.

```
Future<void> confirmRegistration(String email, String username) async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: ConfirmRegistrationStatus.submitting,
        ),
      );
      final userId = await _iAuthFacade.confirmSignUp(
        email: email,
        confirmationCode: state.confirmCode,
      );
        await _iAuthFacade.createNewUser(
          username: username,
          emailAddress: email,
          userId: userId!,
        );
      emit(state.copyWith(status: ConfirmRegistrationStatus.submitted));
    } on AuthFailure catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: ConfirmRegistrationStatus.error,
          failure: AuthFailure(message: e.message),
        ),
      );
    }
```

but when i created a diffrent page or dummy page with just setstate it gave me the right result without returning null.
This is it below.

```
Future<String?> get user async {
    try {
      final user = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
      log('user was checked');
      return user.userId;
    } catch (e) {
      log('no user was found');
      return null;
    }
  }

Future<String?> confirmUser() async {
    try {
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
          username: 'johnblle@gmail.com', confirmationCode: '615841');

      log('confirm user was triggerd');
      setState(() {
        isCompleteSignUpComplete = result.isSignUpComplete;
      });
      return result.isSignUpComplete ? user : null;
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      log(e.message);
    }
  }
Future<void> createNewUser({
    required String username,
    required String emailAddress,
    required String userId,
  }) async {
    try {
      final newUser = User(
        id: userId,
        username: username,
        email: emailAddress,
        dateCreated: TemporalDateTime.now(),
      );
      log('new user wa created');
      await Amplify.DataStore.save(newUser);
    } on DataStoreException catch (e) {
      log(e.message);
    }
  }
Future<void> confirmSignUpAndRegUser() async {
    log('confirmed signup and created new user');
    final userId = await confirmUser();
    log(userId.toString());
    await createNewUser(
      username: 'johnblll',
      emailAddress: 'johnblle@gmail.com',
      userId: userId!,
    );
  }
```